# Waypoints not working properly with my sidenav

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, jquery-waypoints

I'm attempting to make a side nav on my site which adds the "active" class to it's four buttons but I cannot seem to make it work properly.

I've successfully added waypoints to the code but they always seem to be a little off and it takes a bit of extra scrolling from the user to activate the waypoint. I've also tried to follow the {offset} rules in the documentation but to no veil. They either stop working properly from last to first or they stop doing so from first to last.

In order to make the sidenav work, I've split the page in columns, as shown in the CSS below. Feel free to provide insight on the code, as this is a learning exercise and I KNOW my code is pretty dirty at the moment (particularly Javascript)

The side nav:

```
<div class="sidebar verticalized" id="sidebar-verticalized">
  <ul id="sidenav" class="side nav-fixed hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li class="side-link">
      <a class="side-link-first link1" onclick="clickOne()" href="#">01</a>
    </li>
    <li class="side-link">
      <a href="#portfolio" onclick="clickTwo()" class="link2">02</a>
    </li>
    <li class="side-link">
      <a href="#what-we-do" onclick="clickThree()" class="link3">03</a>
    </li>
    <li class="side-link">
      <a href="#contact" onclick="clickFour()" class="link4">04</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html {
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

.page{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
}
.sidebar{
position:fixed;
width:300px;
}
.main{
grid-column-start:2;
}
.verticalized {
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
float: left;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
left:9%;
}
```

my mess of JS (each section is declared below):

```
var $section1 = $('.header');
var $section2 = $('.portfolio');
var $section3 = $('.what-we-do');
var $section4 = $('.contact');
var $link1 = $('.link1');
var $link2 = $('.link2');
var $link3 = $('.link3');
var $link4 = $('.link4');

$section1.waypoint(function (){
  $link1.addClass('active');
  $link2.removeClass('active');
  $link3.removeClass('active');
  $link4.removeClass('active');
});

$section2.waypoint(function(){
  $link1.removeClass('active');
  $link2.addClass('active');
  $link3.removeClass('active');
  $link4.removeClass('active');
});

$section3.waypoint(function(){
  $link1.removeClass('active');
  $link2.removeClass('active');
  $link3.addClass('active');
  $link4.removeClass('active');
});

$section4.waypoint(function(){
  $link1.removeClass('active');
  $link2.removeClass('active');
  $link3.removeClass('active');
  $link4.addClass('active');
});
```

What I've tried so far:

Offset: bottom-in-view (sections are sometimes too large and therefore the old active element remains)

Offset: +/- x% (This fixes the issue from one end but not the other one: I could be going from 1 to 4 on links and it works, but 4 to 1 is broken and vice versa)

Any and all advice/tips are welcome. I'm trying to imitate the bootstrap navbar behaviour with active items for each section.

Comment: Please add code snippet to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <!-- jQuery library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Popper JS -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

           <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
      html, body {
          overflow-x: hidden;
          height: 100%;
      }
      body {
          background: #fff;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
      }
      .header {
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 100%;
          box-shadow: none;
          background-color: #FC466B;
          position: fixed;
          height: 60px!important;
          overflow: hidden;
          z-index: 10;
      }
      .main {
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
          margin-top: 60px;
      }
      .mainInner{
          display: table;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
      }
      .mainInner div{
          display:table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
          font-size: 3em;
          font-weight: bold;
          letter-spacing: 1.25px;
      }
      #sidebarMenu {
          height: 100%;
          position: fixed;
          left: 0;
          width: 250px;
          margin-top: 60px;
          transform: translateX(-250px);
          transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
          background:#414956;
      }
      .sidebarMenuInner{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
      }
      .sidebarMenuInner li{
          list-style: none;
          color: #fff;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 20px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
      }
      .sidebarMenuInner li span{
          display: block;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
      }
      .sidebarMenuInner li a{
          color: #fff;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: bold;
          cursor: pointer;
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
          transform: translateX(0);
      }

      input[type=checkbox] {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          display: none;
      }
      .sidebarIconToggle {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 99;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          top: 22px;
          left: 15px;
          height: 22px;
          width: 22px;
      }
      .spinner {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          position: absolute;
          height: 3px;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #fff;
      }
      .horizontal {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          margin-top: 3px;
      }
      .diagonal.part-1 {
          position: relative;
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          float: left;
      }
      .diagonal.part-2 {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          margin-top: 3px;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          opacity: 0;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          transform: rotate(135deg);
          margin-top: 8px;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          transform: rotate(-135deg);
          margin-top: -9px;
      }
      </style>
      <body>

      <div class="header"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
        <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
          <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
          <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
          <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
        </label>
        <div id="sidebarMenu">
          <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
            <li><a href="#">Jelena Jovanovic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="">YouTube</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Linkedin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='center' class="main center">
          <div class="mainInner">
            <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mainInner">
            <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mainInner">
            <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>`enter code here`
```